# Nested scroll view content with text input layouts behind button

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-textinputlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am currently creating a screen for the user to input some information.

The basic structure of the screen is a collapsible toolbar, a nested scroll view with a bunch of text input layouts and a sticky button at the bottom to go the next screen.

My problem now is that the last text input layout is behind the bottom button and only after focusing any text input layout the last text input layout is shown

Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_done"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="NestedScrollview" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Input" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- repeat the above text input layout until it fills the screen -->

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="HiddenInput" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!-- this is the last text input layout that disappears behind the button -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image: nested scrollview hiding the last text input layout]

The last text input layout with the hint "HiddenInput" is not shown - it simply disappears behind the button. But after focusing any text input layout the last text input layout is suddenly shown:

[image: last text input layout is shown]

This seems to be an issue when coordinator layout, nested scroll view and text input layout are used in combination. I tried for example:

- Same screen without coordinator layout: last input was shown as intended
- Same screen with text views instead of text input layouts: last view is shown as intended

Is there any workaround for this? Or a different way to xml structure to achieve the same goal? Or am I simply missing some xml property?